# Looking for a counter-example in Multi-variable Calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, examples-counterexamples

I looking for a proof or a counterexample (more likely) for the following Claim:

**Claim.** *Let $\,\boldsymbol{f}:U\to\mathbb R^n$, where $U\subset\mathbb R^m$ open, and $\boldsymbol{a}\in U$, be a function with the property that, there exists a matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$, such that for every smooth curve $\boldsymbol{\gamma}: I\to U$, where $I$ is an open interval and $0\in I$, with $\boldsymbol{\gamma}(0)=\boldsymbol{a}$ and $\boldsymbol{\gamma}'(0)\ne \boldsymbol{0}$, the composition 
$h(t)=\boldsymbol{f}\big(\boldsymbol{\gamma}(t)\big)$ is differentiable at $t=0$ and $h'(0)=A\boldsymbol{\gamma}'(0)$. Then $\boldsymbol{f}$ is differentiable at $\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{a}$.*

So far, available are the following examples (which do not consist counterexamples of the above):

A. $f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}\displaystyle
\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^6} & if & (x,y)\ne (0,0), \\
0 & if & (x,y)=(0,0).
\end{array}\right.$

For this $f$ all the directional derivatives exist, but $f$ is not even continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$

B. $f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}\displaystyle
\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} & if & (x,y)\ne (0,0), \\
0 & if & (x,y)=(0,0).
\end{array}\right.$

For this $f$, the composition $h=f\circ\boldsymbol\gamma$ is differentiable at $t=0$ and it is a function of $\boldsymbol\gamma'(0)$, but it does not depend linearly on $\boldsymbol\gamma'(0)$.
In particular, if $\boldsymbol\gamma'(0)=(a,b)\ne (0,0)$, then 
$h'(0)=\displaystyle\frac{a^3}{a^2+b^2}$.

Comment: This comment might be completely wrong or not useful: It sounds like you are asking, given that a composite function is differentiable (i.e. the "left hand side of the chain rule equation exists"), then the derivative of the outside function must exist (the "right hand side of the chain rule equation") 
. Let's look at $F(x) = |x - 5|$. This function is differentiable at $x = 0$ and equal to $-1$. But $F(x)$ is also equal to $f\circ g$ where $f = \sqrt{x}$ and $g = (x - 5)^2$. But the outside function $f$ is not differentiable at $0$

Comment: Nevermind the last comment is wrong. $f \; '$ doesn't exist at $0$. But in the chain rule, $f \; '$ would be evaluated at $g(0) = 25$ so the derivative exists and the above comment wasn't a counter example

Answer (score 2):

I claim that there is a sequence $p_n$ in $\mathbb R^2$ such that $p_n \to (0,0)$ as $n \to \infty$, but no smooth curve $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0)=0$ and $\gamma'(0) \ne 0$ passes through infinitely many $p_n$.

Namely, identifying $\mathbb R^2$ with $\mathbb C$ for convenience, take $p_n = n^{-2} \exp(2 n\pi \alpha i)$ where $\alpha$ is a quadratic irrational.  Quadratic irrationals are poorly approximated by rationals, i.e. there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that
for all positive integers $n$ and all integers $k$, $|\alpha - k/n| \ge \epsilon/n^2$.  This implies that (with a slightly different $\epsilon$), for integers $m \ne n$ we have
$$|\exp(2n \pi \alpha i) - \exp(2m \pi \alpha i)| = |\exp(2(n-m)\pi \alpha i) - 1| \ge \frac{\epsilon}{n-m}$$
Now suppose $\gamma$ is a smooth curve passing through $0$.  For convenience I'll parametrize it so that $|\gamma(t)| = |t|$ for $t$ in some interval $(-\delta, \delta)$.  Thus in this interval,
$\gamma(t) = t \exp(i\phi(t))$, where $\phi(t) = \phi_0 + O(t)$.  In particular if $\gamma(t)$ passes through
$p_n$ and $p_m$ with $m > n$, $$\frac{\epsilon}{n-m} \le \left|\exp\left(i\phi\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right) - \exp\left(i\phi\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right)\right)\right| = O(1/n^2)$$
which is impossible.

Now define $f$ to be the indicator function of the sequence $p_n$, i.e. $f(p_n) = 1$ but $f(z) = 0$ if $z$ is not in the sequence, and
take $\alpha = 0$.  As shown above, the smooth curve $\gamma$  hits only finitely many $p_n$, so $f(\gamma(t)) = 0$ for $t$ in some interval around $0$, and of course this is differentiable at $0$ with $A = 0$.  But $f$ is not differentiable, indeed not continuous, at $0$.